# Error: Cannot find module 'semver' when I run firebase deploy--only functions

Tags: android-studio, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

When I run firebase deploy --only functions on Node.js command prompt, I got this error.

[Command prompt error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tQYT.png)

Comment: Please add the error prompt in the way that community can copy-paste it. This will increase  chance that someone will help you. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please add code function code sample usualy `index.js` (or part if its too long). I think it would be good to add the `package.json` as well.

Comment: Add code not image : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

for me, I workaround updating npm:

```
 npm update -g
```

now it deploys when doing:

```
firebase deploy --only functions
```